# AS3: testHitObject with multiple shape objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Hi I have one question that is hard to explain in words so let me just put up a picture and then try to explain. Since I am a new user at stackoverflow I cant upload pictures in post so I will put a link: http://tinypic.com/r/kbrpt2/6

**What do I want:**
 I want to be able to move my player(blue ball) to point 2 and call function player.hitTestObject(Wall) and get back the value false
**So my problem is**:
When I move player(blue ball) to point 1 or 2 and call function player.hitTestObject(Wall) it returns value true
**So basically:**
 I want that function player.hitTestObject(Wall) returns true ONLY when touching the gray part of an object (shapes), and I want it to return false when player object is in the middle of Wall object but NOT touching grey parts (shapes).
**One solution (but not optimal):**
 One solution is that you create 3 objects and than test 3 times to see if player object has touch any walls, and that is OK in this simple example but if you create bigger objects code starts to look messy.
So if anybody knows **any other solution** I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe hitTestObject uses the bounding box of the clip to check for collisions.  You may want to look at hitTestPoint instead

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint()

The idea here is that your wall would call hitTestPoint against the point's x/y.  Make sure you set the shapeFlag to true, e.g.

myWall.hitTestPoint(point.x, point.y, true);

My two cents -- I believe that these built in collision methods are pretty slow.  If you can break your walls up into individual rectangles, you may be able to check collisions with basic math in a more performant way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you think that is better solution to do it by math and x,y cord then to use hitTestPoint() and hitTestObject() ?

Comment: yep, it is quite a bit faster to check if a point is within a rectangle.  Here's a simple speed test I just whipped up - http://pastebin.com/iqad7x72

Comment: Worth noting, it's significantly faster to do rectangle math like (rect.x + rect.width) to get the right edge of the rectangle instead of using flash's native function rect.right, so I included it in the test.